# PHP SOAP - SOAP-ERROR

Tags: php, xml, soap, php-7, soapclient

Boa tarde
Pessoal, estou fazendo um WEBSERVICE para consumir uma API de uma empresa. Porém com o codigo abaixo o retorno é sempre "SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'Ativo' property" eu não sei mais o que tentar alguém pode dar uma dica.

```
<?php

$wsdl = 'http://layer.ezcommerce.com.br/CatalogoWS.svc?singleWsdl';
$method = 'SalvarMarca';
$login = 'login';
$password = 'senha';

$arrContextOptions = [
    "ssl" => [
        "verify_peer" => false,
        "verify_peer_name" => false,
        'crypto_method' => STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT,
    ]
];

$options = [
    'uri' => 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/',
    'style' => SOAP_RPC,
    'use' => SOAP_ENCODED,
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    'connection_timeout' => 500,
    'trace' => true,
    'encoding' => 'UTF-8', //ISO-8859-1
    'exceptions' => true,
    'stream_context' => stream_context_create($arrContextOptions),
    'login' => $login,
    'password'=> $password
];

$wsu = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/utility';

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl,$options);
$soapHeaders[] = new SoapHeader($wsu, 'UsernameToken', $login, $password);
$client->__setSoapHeaders($soapHeaders);

$params[] = [
    'marca' => [
        'MarcaID' => 8888, //int 8 obrigatorio
        'Nome' => 'MARCA MAICON', //string 50 obrigatorio
        'Url' => "http://wwww.incoterm.com.br",
        'Logotipo' => '', //string 50 obrigatorio
        'Ordem' => 111, //int 8 nao_obrigatorio
        'ativo' => true, //boolean true/false obrigatorio
        'CodigoIntegracao' => '1999999'
    ]
];

$request = new SoapVar($params, XSD_ANYXML);

try {
    $result = $client->__soapCall($method, $params);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $result = $e;
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: O parametro correto é 'ativo' ou 'Ativo'?

Answer (score 2):

Mensagem: "SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'Ativo' property

A sua mensagem de erro indica que espera um objeto com nome "Ativo" e não encontra.

Tenta, por favor, mudar o parâmetro de 'ativo' para 'Ativo', ficando:

```
$params[] =  ['marca'=>[
    'MarcaID'=>8888, //int 8 obrigatorio
    'Nome'=>'MARCA MAICON', //string 50 obrigatorio
    'Url'=>"http://wwww.incoterm.com.br",
    'Logotipo'=>'', //string 50 obrigatorio
    'Ordem'=> 111, //int 8 nao_obrigatorio
    'Ativo'=> true, //boolean true/false obrigatorio
    'CodigoIntegracao'=>'1999999']
];
```

Espero que ajude.